# Unity - Lines after yield not getting executed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code is inside an IEnumerator:

```
 WWW post = new WWW(post_url);
 yield return post; 
 Debug.Log("Id: " + post.text); //This line does not get executed
```

Any idea why the statements after the yield are never getting executed?

I also tried `yield return new WaitWhile(() => hs_post.isDone==true)` but lines ahead still don't get executed

Edit: As requested by comment, here is the entire code:

```
//Called on button click
public void ShowLB(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetString ("Username", input.text);
    Debug.Log ("Showing leaderboard");
    StartCoroutine (InitRow ());
    this.gameObject.SetActive (false);
}

private IEnumerator InitRow(){
    string secretKey = "youDontNeedToKnow";
    string name = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("Username");
    string addScoreURL = ("https://mywebsite.com/insert.php?");
    string hash = Md5Sum(name + 0 + secretKey);
    string post_url = addScoreURL + "name=" + WWW.EscapeURL(name) + "&score=" + 0 + "&hash=" + hash;
    WWW hs_post = new WWW(post_url);
    yield return hs_post;

    if (hs_post.error != null) {
        Debug.Log ("There was an error posting the high score: " + hs_post.error);
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("No error");
    }
    Debug.Log("Id: " + hs_post.text);

    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Because you are returning value. Just move debug line above return

Comment: @Demon I need to get the text from post so I can't do the debug before waiting for the WWW to finish executing.

Comment: When and where do you call the function? Can you that in code and the complete function?

Comment: Could be because you didn't use `StartCoroutine()` and called the method directly instead

Comment: @Programmer Just added the entire code.

Comment: @SwiftingDuster No, I did call StartCoroutine(), as also seen in the edited post with complete code

Comment: See the possible reasons from the duplicate.

Comment: Yes that's it. I disabled the object after starting coroutine hence it must have stopped working. Thanks! I did search before posting but did not locate that answer earlier perhaps since keywords did not match. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I have already marked your question as a duplicate after your comment which means I can't answer it. Although, you should leave this question up so that it can help others.